# SpringBoot + Spring Cloud Stream: Expose /actuator/ endpoints to the web without webflux / web jars

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator

Small question regarding `SpringBoot` + `Spring Cloud` Stream application please.

I have a pure consumer app based on `SpringBoot` and `Spring Cloud` Stream.
It is a "only consuming messages from `kafka` consumer app", in has no http or `rest endpoints` to be exposed as part of its business logic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>streamreactiveconsumer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If you look at the dependency, the dependecy to `spring cloud`, to `boot`, to `actuator` are there. However, there is no dependency to neither `webflux`, neither web. The application is currently able to process all data.

As a plus, I would like to have the actuators endpoints as they are really useful to even a `"just kafka messages consumer app"`.

Unfortunately, the current setup, even with actuator jar imported, the applicaiton does not expose the `/actuator` rest endpoint.

I was wondering, would it be possible to just expose actuator endpoints, without having to carry `webflux` or web please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean; how do you expect the `/actuator` REST endpoint to be available without a web container such as Tomcat?

The actuator endpoints require spring web support (either type).

Comment: this answer is correct. Even if for just two endpoints, we need to carry the whole webflux or web jar. Upvoted and accepted